# adding a column on the parseserver?

Tags: java, android, parse-server

This code should create a new column of name that is stored in string a but it does not return any output on the parse server why?

```
String a;
    public void Onclick(View view)
    {
        ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        EditText text3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        if(intent.getExtras()!=null) {
            a = intent.getStringExtra("this is a");
            Log.i("this is a", a);
        }
            ParseObject b=new ParseObject("User");
        b.put(a,text3.getText().toString());
        list2.add(text3.getText().toString());
        ArrayAdapter<String> a=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list2);
        list.setAdapter(a);
    }
```

Comment: what server are you talking about? I don't see anything about it in the code.

Comment: it is a parse server you can see the parseobject through which have tried to create a new column

Comment: all you did was create a ParseObject object... that's it.

Comment: yes please assume that the connection to the parse server is made because that information cannot be shown on public because then anyone can use the id and access it this program is a small part of the complete program but the error is on this part if the program

Comment: I don't understand how you expect help. Are we supposed to guess what ParseObject does?

Comment: did you save your object calling saveInBackground()

Comment: oh yes got it thanks